# Is it safe to combine AES with TLS?

Tags: encryption, tls, aes

Given that two clients want to sync data through a server, is it safe to use AES to encrypt the data and TLS to communicate with the server?

Assumptions:

- Server has never access to unencrypted data / messages
- Clients use a pre-shared secret for AES encryption without a server being involved

Comment: TLS is a security protocol which may utilize a number of encryption algorithms, such as DES, RC4, or AES.  AES is an encryption algorithm.  So it's not clear what you're asking.  Are you asking if TLS using AES is safe, or safer than TLS with DES/RC4/Other?  Or are you thinking of encrypting your data separately with AES and then transmit it using TLS (which would also involve AES/DES/RC4/Other)?

Comment: I'm thinking of encrypting the data with AES and then transmitting it using TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS is a protocol for establishing the symmetric key that will be used for encrypting data/messages between two endpoints. So if the client communicates with server through the TLS protocol, they will only negotiate (safely), the key that will ultimately be used by each to encrypt/decrypt the data using an algorithm like AES.

To serve your purpose, you will need to encrypt the data one more time with a symmetric key that the two clients (and not the server) are aware of. The suggestion of course assumes a lot about the way you are passing info from clientA->server->clientB.